# What is the smallest AWS EC2 instance I can run a postgres db on?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There is the free tier on AWS and I can get a micro EC2 instance for free essentially.. or close to.. I'm sure setting up elastic ips - loads balancers etc is extra.

Would it effectively be possible for me to run a postgres DB  - for a small api. Roughly about 50 inserts + 50 reads per second ... say about 6000 operations per min at the most.

I can't seem to find anything online - which makes me think that this might be a silly idea.

For this not to be an "open question" - it's simply:  Is it possible and realistic to expect usable performance on an EC2 instance running my postgres DB.

Comment: What about RDS postgresql free tier, you have db.t2.micro with 20 GB storage

Comment: yeh I did think about this.. but if we were to scale quickly and based on possible PR coming up for the project this could possibly hit a ceiling pretty quick. RDS is also notoriously expensive once you get onto a paid plan. I'd even go so far as to say - it's just not a solution that scales well as a result of affordability for many startups who are strapped for cash and have a large user base.

Comment: You can always start small and then scale up if needed. Change instance to better one, change storage type to faster one, migrate to rds. So I would start with the free mode, do some performance tests representative of your usage, and go from there.

Comment: it depends what the 50 inserts and 50 reads per second do, how many rows your Db has etc etc.  Postgresql will run on a machine with 1GB of RAM, so it's possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to determine whether the database can handle a particular workload is to **test it** at that capacity. Launch the database, simulate traffic and monitor its performance. Please note that every application uses a database differently, so nobody can provide "general advice" as to whether a particular-sized database would meet the needs of your particular application.

If you are going to run 'production' workloads, try to **avoid using** the [Burstable performance instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html) (T2, T3) since they can hit limits under heavy workloads unless the 'Unlimited' option is selected. T2/T3 is great for bursty workloads, but not for sustained workloads.

Comparing `m5.xlarge` between EC2 and RDS:

- Amazon EC2: `19.2c/hr` ($4.61/day)
- Amazon RDS: `35.6c/hr` ($8.54/day)

For the additional price, Amazon RDS provides a fully-managed database, automated backups, CloudWatch metrics, etc. This is probably worth much more than $4 of your time every day.

Alternatively, if you can modify your application to use NoSQL instead of SQL, you could use **Amazon DynamoDB** where the capacity you mention would cost 4c/hour ($1/day) plus request and storage costs.

Don't underspend on your database — it powers everything you do. Instead, try to save money by turning off non-production systems when they aren't being used (eg weekends and evenings). That will hopefully give you enough savings to afford an appropriately-powered database.